# Append multiple values for one key from a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, duplicates, append

I am new to python I have a dictionary which has many duplicate keys

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2','key1': 'value3', 'key3': 'value4','key1': 'value5'......}
```

want output like this

```
{
"key1": [value1,value3,value5],
"key2": [value2],
"key3": [value4]
```

}

how can i do it?

Comment: You can't, because a dictionary can't have duplicate keys. Just listing them in a dictionary view (the literal syntax you used) *doesn't work*; you are left with a dictionary with only the last value named for a given key.

Comment: you can't have duplicate key but you can find some method to resolve as : http://www.wellho.net/mouth/3934_Multiple-identical-keys-in-a-Python-dict-yes-you-can-.html

Comment: I'm also thinking your object is probably not a python dictionary. what type is your object (can get this from `type(your-object-name)`? or can you show us the raw output from printing your object?

Comment: If you have some data structure which you can iterate over to get key-value-pairs then you can populate an output dictionary using `output.setdefault(key, []).append(value)` But I'm pretty sure I have seen this question before; just can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to achieve this from a list/tuple containing duplicated keys, you could do:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dupes = (('k1', 1), ('k2', 2), ('k1', 3), ('k3', 4))
res = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in dupes:
    res[k].append(v)

print(res)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'k3': [4], 'k2': [2], 'k1': [1, 3]})
```